# VS403091: You specified a state xxx that is already added

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I got this error while trying to create a copy of a process inherited from the Agile process on Azure Devops. I've inspected everything about the process including its WITs and their respective states but I couldn't find anything.

I'll be glad if anyone who has experienced this issue can advise on a way out. The error message is not really straightforward.

Comment: This error should related to the process inherited from the Agile, what states did you add to the inherited process? You could double check it. As test, you could create a new  process inherited from the Agile process without adding any state then create a copy of a process, check if you still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be a known issue and the Azure DevOps Product Group is investigating it.

Follow this thread for any related updates: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/924749/create-a-copy-of-an-existing-process-template-fail.html

and/or feel free to add your findings to it.

Here is another related thread for your reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/917687/cant-copy-process-error-vs403091.html