# Can't Create Copy of Agile Process

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a copy of the process we're using in Azure DevOps, but I'm unable to do so. I'm encountering the error shown below. Maybe someone can shed some light with this. Thanks.

[image: Azure DevOps Error]

Comment: How are you trying to copy it?

Comment: In Azure DevOps, in the Organization Settings, under Process, there's an option to create a copy of the process. After specifying a name for the new process, it throws that error.

Comment: This problem was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173940/vs403091-you-specified-a-state-xxx-that-is-already-added. Try solutions from that post.

Comment: Give a try with the workaround,  temporarily disable all states and try to copy the process again. Kindly check if this do the trick.